# How to have multiple parameters using Spring MVC RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC `RequestMapping` here for `GET` parameters. Below is my code -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HashMap<String, String> handleRequest(@RequestParam("dc1Servers") String dc1Servers) {
    HashMap<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String helloWorld = "Hello World!";
    model.put("greeting", helloWorld);

    System.out.println(dc1Servers);

    return model;
}
```

I am hitting this URL - `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataweb/index?dc1Servers=7` then it goes into the above code and prints out `7` on the console and works fine.

Now I would like to have these two below parameters as well -

```
dc2Servers=7
dc3Servers=7
```

So I made a method like this which can take three input parameters -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HashMap<String, String> handleRequest(@RequestParam("dc1Servers") String dc1Servers, @RequestParam("dc2Servers") String dc2Servers, @RequestParam("dc3Servers") String dc3Servers) {
    HashMap<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String helloWorld = "Hello World!";
    model.put("greeting", helloWorld);

    System.out.println(dc1Servers);
    System.out.println(dc2Servers);
    System.out.println(dc3Servers);

    return model;
}
```

Now if I hit the url like this then it doesn't works -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataweb/index?dc1Servers=7?dc2Servers=7?dc3Servers=7
```

And it gives me some error.. Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataweb/index?dc1Servers=7&dc2Servers=7&dc3Servers=7
```

change an try again

> & works between each parameter
>
> ? only works at the begin of the url parameters

Check this example

> http://www.example.com/products/women/dresses?sessionid=34567&source=google.com

Comment: Can you help me on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923857/how-to-pass-list-parameters-for-each-object-using-spring-mvc) as well? Thanks for the help.